# How to Use CSV file in Django to Generate Graphs?

Tags: python, django, csv, plot

I want to Generate Graphs in Django View Using CSV file.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please post code of what you have already tried, and your specific questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the data from the CSV. You can just any Javascript charting library on the frontend to process the data. [Chart.js is an option](https://www.chartjs.org/)

```
import csv
def chart_data(request):
    data = []
    with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            data.append(row)

    return render(request, 'template.html',
                  {'data': data})
```